# 3 or 4 tikz figures side-by-side

Tags: graphics, subfloats

How could I have a figure with 3 or 4 subfigures side-by-side in the same row? I've tried it once but the best I had was only 2 subfigures side-by-side in the same row.

My code so far is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,twoside,openright]{article}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption} 

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.30\textwidth}
\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,3) node[left] {$\text{A}$} to[out=0,in=90] (3,0) node[below]{$\text{B}$};
    \draw[->, very thick] (-.1,0) -- (4,0) node[below] {$\text{αγαθό Α}$};
    \draw[->, very thick] (0,-.1) -- (0,4) node[left]{$\text{αγαθό Β}$};
\draw[ForestGreen] (0,2)  node[left] {$\text{Η}$} to [out=0, in=90] (2,0)node[below]{$\text{Θ}$};
\draw[<-, Cyan] (45:2.1) -- (45:2.9);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \label{fig:subfig8}
          \caption{}
       \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.30\textwidth}
\centering
           \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,3) node[left] {$\text{A}$} to[out=0,in=90] (3,0) node[below]{$\text{B}$};
    \draw[->, very thick] (-.1,0) -- (4,0) node[below] {$\text{αγαθό Α}$};
    \draw[->, very thick] (0,-.1) -- (0,4) node[left]{$\text{αγαθό Β}$};
\draw[ForestGreen] (0,2.7)  node[left] {$\text{Γ}$} to [out=0, in=90] (1.5,0)node[below]{$\text{Δ}$};
\draw[<-, Cyan] (45:2.2) -- (45:2.9);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \label{fig:subfig9}
          \caption{}
          \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}
\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,3) node[left] {$\text{A}$} to[out=0,in=90] (3,0) node[below]{$\text{B}$};
    \draw[->, very thick] (-.1,0) -- (4,0) node[below] {$\text{αγαθό Α}$};
    \draw[->, very thick] (0,-.1) -- (0,4) node[left]{$\text{αγαθό Β}$};
\draw[ForestGreen] (0,1.5)  node[left] {$\text{E}$} to [out=0, in=90] (2.5,0)node[below]{$\text{Z}$};
\draw[<-, Cyan] (45:2.1) -- (45:2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{fig:subfig10}
          \caption{}
     \end{subfigure}
\captionof{figure}{τεχνολογία και στα δυο αγαθά} \label{fig:subfig1.a.4}
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 31):

The following code is used for 3, it requires the `subcaption` package. If have more than 3 change the `0.30\textwidth` parameter of the `subfigure` to resize each of them accordingly

```
 \begin{figure}
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.30\textwidth}
          \centering
          \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\input{figures/a.tikz}}  
          \caption{Caption A}
          \label{fig:A}
     \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.30\textwidth}
          \centering
          \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\input{figures/b.tikz}}  
          \caption{Caption B}
          \label{fig:B}
     \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.30\textwidth}
          \centering
          \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\input{figures/c.tikz}}  
          \caption{Caption C}
          \label{fig:C}
     \end{subfigure}
 \end{figure}
```

---

**EDIT**: I've taken the time to fix your code. You were missing the `\resizebox` in order to properly locate your tikz figures. See code and results below

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,twoside,openright]{article}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption} 

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw (0,3) node[left] {$\text{A}$} to[out=0,in=90] (3,0) node[below]{$\text{B}$};
                \draw[->, very thick] (-.1,0) -- (4,0) node[below] {$\text{αγαθό Α}$};
                \draw[->, very thick] (0,-.1) -- (0,4) node[left]{$\text{αγαθό Β}$};
                \draw[ForestGreen] (0,2)  node[left] {$\text{Η}$} to [out=0, in=90] (2,0)node[below]{$\text{Θ}$};
                \draw[<-, Cyan] (45:2.1) -- (45:2.9);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \caption{Subfigure A}
        \label{fig:subfig8}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
    \centering
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw (0,3) node[left] {$\text{A}$} to[out=0,in=90] (3,0) node[below]{$\text{B}$};
                \draw[->, very thick] (-.1,0) -- (4,0) node[below] {$\text{αγαθό Α}$};
                \draw[->, very thick] (0,-.1) -- (0,4) node[left]{$\text{αγαθό Β}$};
                \draw[ForestGreen] (0,2.7)  node[left] {$\text{Γ}$} to [out=0, in=90] (1.5,0)node[below]{$\text{Δ}$};
                \draw[<-, Cyan] (45:2.2) -- (45:2.9);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \caption{Subfigure B}   
        \label{fig:subfig9}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw (0,3) node[left] {$\text{A}$} to[out=0,in=90] (3,0) node[below]{$\text{B}$};
                \draw[->, very thick] (-.1,0) -- (4,0) node[below] {$\text{αγαθό Α}$};
                \draw[->, very thick] (0,-.1) -- (0,4) node[left]{$\text{αγαθό Β}$};
                \draw[ForestGreen] (0,1.5)  node[left] {$\text{E}$} to [out=0, in=90] (2.5,0)node[below]{$\text{Z}$};
                \draw[<-, Cyan] (45:2.1) -- (45:2.5);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \caption{Subfigure C}
        \label{fig:subfig10}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{τεχνολογία και στα δυο αγαθά} 
\label{fig:subfig1.a.4}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I hope this helps!

Update: Fixed missing `{` in resizeboxes.

Comment: Perhaps you should mention that your code requires the `subcaption` package.

Comment: If I use the subfigure package, does the code change?

Comment: @giannis Yes, it changes. You shouldn't use `subfigure`  as it is deprecated. You are better off with `subcaption`

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful. I'd like to add, however, that the caption (a), (b), (c) of each subfigure is not centered below of figure. I've tried also \centering but still they aren't centered.

Comment: @giannis I've updated the coude, the `\centering` in the example should do the work. A minimal working example of your code that let us see exactly what are you trying to do would help.

Comment: @Dan I've updated my question.

Comment: @Dan I'd like to know, if that's possible, how could we use the subfigure package having the same result... I think it gives a better result, but still I'm not sure...

Comment: @giannis I've updated my answer, fixing your code.

Comment: `\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}\input{figures/a.tikz}}` (and other `resize` boxes) have a missing `{`. It should be: `\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\input{figures/a.tikz}}`. Just trying to save others some time.