# How to draw 3 figures and have them side by side while they're connected

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, captions, subfloats

I would like to have 3 figures side by side, as [in one of my previous posts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120982/3-or-4-tikz-figures-side-by-side). However, this time isn't the same. I would like to link my figures as below: 
[image]

My problem is not only how to put my figures side by side (maybe with the `subcaption` package it'll be solved), but also how I could draw these dashed lines?

Comment: Please see revised answer

Comment: Do you want to use raster images for the single pictures, or do you want do draw them with e.g. _pstricks_ or _TikZ_?

Comment: I'd prefer Tikz. But each and every suggestion is really welcome.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would do this using `PGFPlots`, putting three `axis` environments in a single `tikzpicture` and using `\coordinate`s to draw the lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\pgfplotsset{
    giannis/.style={
        anchor=south west,
        axis lines=left,
        scale only axis,
        width=3cm, height=2.5cm,
        domain=0:8,
        xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
        ymin=0, ymax=6,
        xmin=0, xmax=4,
        no markers,
        clip=false,
        cycle list={
            very thick, black\\
            very thick, black\\
        },
        xlabel=Quantity, xlabel style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=north},
        ylabel=Price, ylabel style={at=(current axis.above origin), rotate=-90, anchor=east}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[giannis, name=first, width=2cm]
\addplot coordinates {(0,5) (3,0)};

\coordinate [label=left:a] (a) at (axis cs:0,5);
\coordinate [label=left:d] (d) at (axis cs:0,3);
\node [above right] at (axis cs:1,3) {b};
\end{axis}
\node [yshift=-2ex] at ({current axis.outer south west}-|current axis.south) {(a)};

\begin{axis}[giannis, name=second, xshift=2em, at=(first.south east),width=2cm]
\addplot coordinates {(0,4) (3,0)};

\coordinate (p2-1) at (axis cs:0,3);
\end{axis}
\node [yshift=-2ex] at ({current axis.outer south west}-|current axis.south) {(b)};

\begin{axis}[giannis, xshift=2em, at=(second.south east)]
\addplot table {
0 5
0.5 2

0.5 3.5
2 0
};
\draw  [very thick, densely dashed] (axis cs:0.5,2) -- (axis cs:0.5,3.5);

\addplot table {
0 5
0.5 4
3.5 0
};

\coordinate (a2) at (axis cs:0,5);
\coordinate [label=above right:i] (i) at (axis cs:1.3,3);
\coordinate (i2) at (i|-{axis cs:0,0});

\coordinate (p1-2) at (axis cs:0,5);
\coordinate (p2-2) at (axis cs:1.5,3);
\end{axis}
\node [yshift=-2ex] at ({current axis.outer south west}-|current axis.south) {(c)};

%\draw [thick, red] (a) -- (b);
\draw [gray, densely dashed] (a) -- (a2) (d) -- (i) -- (i2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just I would like to notice something: I see that you have named x-axis as a, b and c. How could I name all x-axis as Q and all y-axis as P, while at the same time having a, b and c so as to point out the different figures.

Comment: @giannis: Where do you want the `Q` labels? in the same position where it currently says `a`, `b`, and `c`? Or at the end of the axis arrows?

Comment: at the of the axis arrows. At the end also of y-axis I'd like the P labels.

Comment: @giannis: I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 10):

I edited my answer to address the OP's revised requirement to add vertical lines to the composite, in addition to the horizontal already requested.

I basically use the same approach as before, but used a `\rotatebox` on a dashed line to get it vertical.  I took the OP's figure (from his question), cropped it into three separate images, and also removed the pre-existing dashed lines from each one.  I therefore added the text `<I did this` to the end of MY lines, so that you wouldn't be confused into thinking I had merely left the OP's original lines in my images.

The key with the `\stackinset` is to specify the coordinate origins, offset, and (in this case) the dashed-line length.  The first argument is the horizontal origin (l,c,r), the next arg is the h-offset to the inset, the 3rd arg is the vertical origin (t,c,b), the next the v-offset of the inset, the 5th arg is the inset item, while the 6th and last item is the background over which to place the inset(s), which can be nested, as shown in the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}[2013-10-15]
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%From morsburg at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12537/
%how-can-i-make-a-horizontal-dashed-line/12553#12553
\def\dashfill{\cleaders\hbox to .6em{-}\hfill}
\newcommand\dashline[1]{\hbox to #1{\textcolor{red}{\dashfill}\hfil}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\stackinset{l}{.47in}{c}{.24in}{\dashline{3.1in}$<$I did this}{%
\stackinset{c}{1in}{b}{.35in}{\rotatebox{90}{\dashline{0.9in}$<$I did this}}{%
\stackunder{\includegraphics[scale=.4]{aelkpA}}{(a)}
\stackunder{\includegraphics[scale=.4]{aelkpB}}{(b)}
\stackunder{\includegraphics[scale=.4]{aelkpC}}{(c)}%
}}
\caption{My figures (a), (b), and (c)}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]