# Side-by-side tikzpicture (use of axis causes problems)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, subcaption

I am struggling with putting three graphs side-by-side in one line. Every solution I could find caused errors because of the usage of axis.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
                    domain=-10:10,
                    grid=major,
                    xmin=-10, xmax=10,
                    ymin=-10, ymax=10,
                    xlabel={x}, ylabel={y},
                    samples=1000,
                    axis y line=center,
                    axis x line=middle
                ]
        \addplot+[mark=none,color=blue] {1 * abs(x-1) + 0};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
                    domain=-10:10,
                    grid=major,
                    xmin=-10, xmax=10,
                    ymin=-10, ymax=10,
                    xlabel={x}, ylabel={y},
                    samples=1000,
                    axis y line=center,
                    axis x line=middle
                ]
        \addplot+[mark=none,color=red] {1 * abs(x-0) + 0};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
                    domain=-10:10,
                    grid=major,
                    xmin=-10, xmax=10,
                    ymin=-10, ymax=10,
                    xlabel={x}, ylabel={y},
                    samples=1000,
                    axis y line=center,
                    axis x line=middle
                ]
        \addplot+[mark=none,color=green] {1 * abs(x+1) + 0};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: That's how it looks at the moment.]

I would like to get these three pictures side-by-side in one line including a caption for each of them + a caption for the whole figure. I tried a lot with figures and subfigures etc., but I always got error messages telling me that something is wrong because of the `\begin{axis}` part. This is how I would like it to look like:

[image: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120982/3-or-4-tikz-figures-side-by-side]

---

### EDIT: @martijnn2008 reply to your comment

I just tried that: [Caption issue when placing figure side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111496/caption-issue-when-placing-figure-side-by-side/111513#111513) - but it doesn't work.

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \resizebox{0.2\textwidth}{!}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                        domain=-10:10,
                        grid=major,
                        xmin=-10, xmax=10,
                        ymin=-10, ymax=10,
                        xlabel={x}, ylabel={y},
                        samples=1000,
                        axis y line=center,
                        axis x line=middle
                    ]
                    \addplot+[mark=none,color=blue] {1 * abs(x-0) + 0};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \caption{A not.}
    \end{minipage}\hfill

    \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \resizebox{0.2\textwidth}{!}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                        domain=-10:10,
                        grid=major,
                        xmin=-10, xmax=10,
                        ymin=-10, ymax=10,
                        xlabel={x}, ylabel={y},
                        samples=1000,
                        axis y line=center,
                        axis x line=middle
                    ]
                    \addplot+[mark=none,color=blue] {1 * abs(x-0) + 0};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \caption{A caption.}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Lorem Ipsum dolor sit atmet.}
\end{figure}
```

As you can see in the image, the two graphs are still not in one row. But we have captions now.

[image]

Comment: Try http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111513/51393

Comment: @martijnn2008 doesn't work. See my edit of the question.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Try removing the blank lines and see if that gets you closer :)

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to @martijnn2008 and @cmhughes! Here is the solution:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.50\textwidth}
        \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                        domain=-10:10,
                        grid=major,
                        xmin=-10, xmax=10,
                        ymin=-10, ymax=10,
                        xlabel={x}, ylabel={y},
                        samples=1000,
                        axis y line=center,
                        axis x line=middle
                    ]
                    \addplot+[mark=none,color=blue] {1 * abs(x-0) + 0};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}

        \caption{$h=0$}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.50\textwidth}
        \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                        domain=-10:10,
                        grid=major,
                        xmin=-10, xmax=10,
                        ymin=-10, ymax=10,
                        xlabel={x}, ylabel={y},
                        samples=1000,
                        axis y line=center,
                        axis x line=middle
                    ]
                    \addplot+[mark=none,color=red] {1 * abs(x-1) + 0};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$h=1$}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{$\forall a, h, k \in \mathbb{R}, f(x) = a \mid x-h \mid + k$}
\end{figure}
```

[image]